# awk sum of column value from 2 adjacent lines while $2 is equal

Tags: awk

A file of 1500 stations is sorted on station and date, and holds daily station precipitation in $4. To get precipitation of 48 hours, I want to add $4 to $4 in the previous row – but only if the station in $2 is still the same.

Currently, my awk computes the sum of $4 of some of 2 adjacent rows, but in no obvious-to-me pattern, it sometimes omits a pair, or sets $4 to "<blank<" suddenly, although $4 in adjacent rows do hold values <>0.
And it also ignores station change in $2.
Help?

My current code:
`awk -F'\;' -v OFS=";" ' stat=$2 p{ print $0, "added "p"p to "$4, " precip in 48 hrs\: "$4+p }{if ($2==stat) p=$4; else p=""}' infile > outfile`

an excerpt of the actual infile:

```
991_20230413;991;20230413;1.5
991_20230414;991;20230414;29
991_20230415;991;20230415;0.1
991_20230416;991;20230416;6.4
998_19480101;998;19480101;7.6
998_19480102;998;19480102;28
998_19480103;998;19480103;6.4
998_19480104;998;19480104;0
```

The excerpt of the current outfile (this is from the middle of a sequence, so the 1.5 on the first line is from the previous line before that):

```
991_20230413;991;20230413;1.5;added 0.3p to 1.5;precip in 48 hrs: 1.8
991_20230414;991;20230414;29;added p to 29.0;precip in 48 hrs: 29
991_20230415;991;20230415;0.1;added 29.0p to 0.1;precip in 48 hrs: 29.1
991_20230416;991;20230416;6.4;added p to 6.4;precip in 48 hrs: 6.4
998_19480101;998;19480101;7.6;added 6.4p to 7.6;precip in 48 hrs: 14
998_19480102;998;19480102;28;added p to 28.0;precip in 48 hrs: 28
998_19480103;998;19480103;6.4;added 28.0p to 6.4;precip in 48 hrs: 34.4
998_19480104;998;19480104;0;added p to 0.0;precip in 48 hrs: 0
```

Desired outfile:

```
991_20230413;991;20230413;1.5;added 0.3p to 1.5;precip in 48 hrs: 1.8
991_20230414;991;20230414;29;added 1.5p to 29.0;precip in 48 hrs: 30.5
991_20230415;991;20230415;0.1;added 29.0p to 0.1;precip in 48 hrs: 29.1
991_20230416;991;20230416;6.4;added 0.1p to 6.4;precip in 48 hrs: 6.5
998_19480101;998;19480101;7.6;added p to 7.6;precip in 48 hrs: 7.6
998_19480102;998;19480102;28;added 7.6p to 28.0;precip in 48 hrs: 35.6
998_19480103;998;19480103;6.4;added 28.0p to 6.4;precip in 48 hrs: 34.4
998_19480104;998;19480104;0;added 6.4p to 0.0;precip in 48 hrs: 6.4
```

A previous attempt computes sum on all rows, not even pairwise.
`awk -F'\;' -v OFS=";" ' NR==1 {p=0; p=$4;next} {p+=$4} {print $0, "added "$4"p to "p, " precip in 48 hrs\: "$4+p }'`

Comment: `stat=$2 p` sets the vaue of `stat` to the concatenation of `$2` and `p`, and executes the action if the result is not false. Is this really what you want? What have you done to debug this?

Comment: Thanks. No. That would not be what I want! For debugging, I tried eg.: stat=$2; p{ print $..  (so added semicolon) Result: in case a sum has been computed it prints $0 twice while one bears the comment fields; omits pairs; ignores station.  Or this: p{ stat=$2; print $... (so put stat into {} Result: zero-size file.

Comment: Where should the `0.3` on the first line come from?

Comment: It's from the previous row in the big file. I'll clarify that infile is actually a not-amended excerpt.

Comment: _Debugging_ means examining what the code does, not making random changes blindly. A common simple debugging technique is to add `print` statements which reveal the state of interesting variables at various points within the script, and checking where what it prints differs from what you expected in order to isolate the parts which work from the parts which don't.

Comment: The comment fields are following your definition of debugging, I reckon.  But I lack knowledge of what can go wrong and where and why to debug better. Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: You've asked a few awk questions now but don't seem to have a grasp of it's basics yet - you might want to get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to use awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correctly guessing what you actually want, try this.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
stat != $2 { p=0; stat=$2 }
{ print $0, "added "p"p to "$4, " precip in 48 hrs\: "$4+p; p=$4 }'
```

Output for your sample data:

```
991_20230413;991;20230413;1.5;added 0p to 1.5; precip in 48 hrs: 1.5
991_20230414;991;20230414;29;added 1.5p to 29; precip in 48 hrs: 30.5
991_20230415;991;20230415;0.1;added 29p to 0.1; precip in 48 hrs: 29.1
991_20230416;991;20230416;6.4;added 0.1p to 6.4; precip in 48 hrs: 6.5
998_19480101;998;19480101;7.6;added 0p to 7.6; precip in 48 hrs: 7.6
998_19480102;998;19480102;28;added 7.6p to 28; precip in 48 hrs: 35.6
998_19480103;998;19480103;6.4;added 28p to 6.4; precip in 48 hrs: 34.4
998_19480104;998;19480104;0;added 6.4p to 0; precip in 48 hrs: 6.4
```

This is a very common grouping pattern; keep on aggregating as long as the field is equal to its previous value, and set the previous value to the current one at the end, in preparation for the next line of input. For beginners it's sometimes confusing that what you do with the current line occasionally anticipates something about the input on the subsequent line, but you quickly get used to it as you play around with Awk.

To do pairwise sums, just set `p` to the value from the current line, so that that's what gets added on the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks. While your awk does observe the station change, it computes the sum of all precipitation in one station. But we need 48 hour cycles: pair-wise sums on consecutive rows (which are deliberately sorted on station and date for this purpose).

Comment: Oh, I see now. Updated the answer; maybe examine the answer's history to see what I changed.

Comment: You did it! Thank you! Unfortunately, I lack awk knowledge to even word the many questions I should now have.  But maybe you can explain what this one bit does – with regards to the rest of the command? stat != $2

Comment: It's a condition which is true when `stat` is not equal to the second field.

Comment: Maybe review the [Stack Overflow `awk` tag info page](/tags/awk/info); it was links to common FAQs and learning resources.